# MTM: Error Sps_spsprodch1su1Configuration

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mtm

What is going on here when this error occurs?

> Circuit Breaker "BaseSqlComponent-Sps_spsprodch1su1Configuration"
>   exceeded the concurrency limit of 160. In the last 10000 milliseconds,
>   there were: 0 failure, 0 timeout, 0 short circuited, and 158 semaphore
>   rejected.

Comment: I have the same problem with Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Same here with VSO. Looks like they are having issues with Hosted Builds. We use "custom" Build agents and are having this problem as well http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/05/05/issues-with-visual-studio-online-hosted-build-5-5-investigating.aspx

Comment: I just had the same error in VS2013.  TFS maybe?